# Processing startup items in OS 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, boot, itunes, nas

I would like to boot Mac OS 10.8 (Mountain Lion) automatically on a timed schedule and then start iTunes to play Music. I use the Aurora app for this. The Problem is that my iTunes Music is on a NAS and the NAS connects after iTunes gets started - so iTunes cannot find the music folder.

Is there a way I can affect the start up procedure so my Mac connects first with the NAS and then starts iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove iTunes from login items and save a property list like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/loginitems.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>loginitems</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>sleep 30;open -a iTunes</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You might use Automator to create an application like this:

[image]

Then add the application to login items.

Comment: thank you. tried as you said, the problem remained: iTunes opened before NAS connected. found a workaround:  scheduled selfstart of the mac and afterwards an automator app launches iTunes.